# Response Content-length mismatch when running Vue SPA in .Net Core App

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vue.js, .net-core

I am starting a Vue SPA inside of a .net core app. The static MVC page is served correctly, but when I navigate to the SPA route I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too many bytes written (2598 of 1372).
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.VerifyAndUpdateWrite(Int32 count)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I have tried reinstalling all node_modules and using the UseVueCli options, but neither have worked. The Vue app is running before starting the .net app.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                "*",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .WithOrigins("")
                        .WithMethods("GET")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });

        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

        //Add all initial dependencies which can be used anywhere
        services.AddInitialDependencies();

        services.AddCaching();
        services.AddResponseCaching();

        services.AddFrameworks();
        services.AddSecurity(Configuration);
        services.AddDbContexts();
        services.AddSettingsProviders();
        services.AddLogicClasses();
        services.AddRealtimeClasses();

        services.AddAutoMapper((IMapperConfigurationExpression mapperConfiguration) =>
        {
            mapperConfiguration.CreateMissingTypeMaps = false;
        });

        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IMapper autoMapper)
    {
        app.StartDbConfiguration(serviceProvider);

        app.UseHttpContextLogging();
        app.ConfigureErrorHandling(env);

        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        app.ConfigureHealthChecks();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseClaimsLogging();

        app.UseResponseCaching();

        app.ConfigureRequestValidation();

        app.UseRewriter();

        app.ConfigureRealtime();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
          routes.MapRoute(
                name: "defaultRoute",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:9051");
            }
        });

        // Configure Kendo UI
        app.UseKendo(env);

        autoMapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

When I navigate to the route that the SPA should be served on, I am returned with the error above.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. The stackify middleware was registered and that was the cause of the problem. Commenting it out resolved the issue.